# Only odd numbers type for Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to have a type that checks if the value is an odd number or not. I tried to find something but I find only hardcoded solutions like `odds: 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 9`. But I want to know is there a dynamic way to do it only with Typescript.

I know that for example in JS we can find out that the number is odd or not with this expression `x % 2 === 1`. I want to know is there a way to define a type with an expression like this.

Comment: Can you provide more information, like the code you may be trying to write it as?  That may help us understand the problem better.

Comment: @RobertHovhannisyan generally `x % 2 == 1` is the way to determine whether a number variable is odd.

Comment: @Daveguy yes I know it, I just want to know is there a way to set it as a type.

Comment: @Daveguy OP is attempting to make a *type* to enforce a number's oddness.

Comment: Just to clarify what does type refer to in this case?  I would've thought the statement i mentioned above would classify as a bool but maybe I am still misunderstanding here.

Comment: @Daveguy A type, as in `const foo: oddInteger` or whatever.

Comment: @Daveguy I want the type to be numbers but only odd numbers, say if someone will type 4, it will throw a type error.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in TypeScript (or most type systems, even).

Comment: @RobertHovhannisyan AFAIK there's no reasonable way to do this in TS like you (kind of) can in something like Haskell.

Comment: OK, thank you all, I just wanted to know is there a way to do it only with TS :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible

```
type OddNumber<
    X extends number,
    Y extends unknown[] = [1],
    Z extends number = never
> = Y['length'] extends X
    ? Z | Y['length']
    : OddNumber<X, [1, 1, ...Y], Z | Y['length']>

type a = OddNumber<1> // 1 
type b = OddNumber<3> // 1 | 3
type c = OddNumber<5> // 1 | 3 | 5
type d = OddNumber<7> // 1 | 3 | 5 | 7
```

with some limitations, input must be an odd number and cannot exceed 1999 (maximum depth of typescript recursion is only 1000)

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gJnAcgVwLYCMICcA8BYAKAEgANKCAD2AgDs4BnKGtTLAGkKIE1yraGoyGgGsaAewDuNANoBdKAF4o0gIyyOxAFq9qdRswzZFTCADdshAHzGu0gOQAbWgHNgACzvzKugSU4B+KG0AHyhbRxd3T04ALlgEFENcEjZlFVT0qAA6HK51IKhQ8KcaVw9ZS0JCUEgoAENjeCQWbBwVawB6DqgVKGrwaHRGhJbcAGZO7t7Qsf7agGNh5qScAFZJnsKoMa3Vueg4JcTWHAB2Dent3a3ToA)

Comment: Is this still the best way?

Comment: I manage to get the number up to 6000 odd numbers, but it is very complicated

Comment: Brilliant! Sucks that JS / TS have handicapped recursion facilities.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe creating a new class can be helpful on this case?

```
class OddNumber {
    value: number;

    constructor(value: number) {
        if (value % 2 != 0)
            throw new Error("Even number is not assignable to type 'OddNumber'.");
        this.value = value;
    }
};

let oddNumber = new OddNumber(4);
console.log(oddNumber.value); // It will log 4
let evenNumber = new OddNumber(5); // It will throw an exception here
console.log(evenNumber.value);
```

Comment: It's a very interesting option, but I was wondering is there a way to do this only with TS. Anyway thank you, it's a very interesting approach and deserves an upvote :)

Comment: This is the practical answer.