# Array with different type when index is odd or even

Tags: typescript

I am looking for a type `OddEvenArray<Odd,Even>`, which can do the following thing typesafe as `OddEvenArray<string,number>`: `["a",1,"b",2]`.

I have no idea to distinguish between odd and even index during typing.

PS: I am sorry, but the JSON I am dealing with looks like that ^^'

Comment: There's no *specific* type that works this way but you could come up with a generic constraint that does.  But must the array be of even length or can it end in the odd one?  Like, is `["a", 1, "b"]` okay or not okay?

Comment: Assuming it must be of even length, then [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WzaQ2m) might meet your needs.  Does it?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what specific use case is unmet?

Comment: @jcalz: Its always of even length :)

Comment: @jcalz: That would be extreamly helpful if you could provide this as answer. This seems like the solution for me

Comment: Looks like AcidCoder's answer is similar so I won't write anything up here unless you tell me it's preferable to the other one.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

this is only possible with function generic, you cannot directly assign this type to a variable, you must check with function

this only works for tuple, not array

```
type Odd<
    X extends number,
    Y extends unknown[] = [1],
    Z extends number = never
> = Y['length'] extends X
    ? Z | Y['length']
    : Odd<X, [1, 1, ...Y], Z | Y['length']>

type OddNumbers = Odd<1999> // 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | ....1997

type IsStringAndOddTuple<T extends unknown[], ACC extends any[]=[]> = 
    T extends [infer A, ...infer J] 
        ? T['length'] extends OddNumbers 
            ? IsStringAndOddTuple<J,[...ACC, A extends number? A : "expect number type at even index" ]>
            : IsStringAndOddTuple<J,[...ACC, A extends string? A : "expect string type at Odd index" ]>
        :ACC

const isStringAndOddTuple =<T extends unknown[]>(tuple: T extends never? T : IsStringAndOddTuple<T>)=>{
  // don't neeed anything here
}

type C = IsStringAndOddTuple<[1, 2, 3, 4]>
//   ^?

type D = IsStringAndOddTuple<["a","b","c","d"]>
//   ^?

type E = IsStringAndOddTuple<["a",1,"b",2]>
//   ^?

isStringAndOddTuple([1, 2, 3, 4]) 
isStringAndOddTuple(["a","b","c","d"]) 
isStringAndOddTuple<["a",1,"b",2]>
```

[image]

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gJnAPAWAFBQ1AGlCAPYCAOzgGcoiBXAWwCMIAnAGjUygE1cDiypKiA1kQD2AdyIBtALpQAvFAkBGKS3SYAWl0IlyVOozkUIAN0ZoAfIfYSA5ABtiAc2AALGzPzbeWVpgD8UJoAPhy2DkTOblK+GABcsAiIWEwKiilpUAB02ewqgVAh1vZOru7maGigkAlwAHI09Azk8vBIigCcnZYA9N1QigVQAMyDAKyDAOyD2dkd7RMVqFXQAJKkAMrADACWEQCCJK0AKpRgDohHWjzk-EJiknl7AMJPVzpQAIZEINKy0pbyGJQS6ea4KXYAMwMexSM0hBgAUjIgWwAkcwiUom9eK16vomlAUWx-FA1psdvtDggTmcIIgEUwJDNnk8UntsboGowAuz4gAifCQADGwAoXIYUGWn1FJmIUF2cHwfKgUnKamJxPiZK2u0cBzgx1O5wZTOyLLZHKgpB1ER5UH5gogIqtNsckvA0A+ota8pISpVao1cRZiyFwiI1vlG1d+sNtLkF0ttxE4n+AApgEaIPEQdx3kRZQw0fbSdGKXqqXAaecjuYAJSycwAb18vSgcHDNlFBYgEDgn2+rl1UBcjAgaAAvospa95Nry7HqVnEEoUgAmFJDFIAFlVaDbGAAen5px6oAARQzz3WLqvLiR8j58ph82jPvlC99wPl71AHqDHqe1QAKJXmWN6VtWdIPk+TBpK+z5rr+-6AagaDbOBlIGkutJpquUAbsMO5SHWhKoBh5IQdhd64TB75vi+n4vt+JFkRRMaQfej7PvBDFIZYQA)

the problem with this method is, it does not support tuple length over 1000 because `IsStringAndOddTuple` max recursion is only 1000

I believe there is a meta solution that can exceed this limitation, but the works are just too much

even so you tuple length cannot exceed 10,000 because max length of a tuple is 10,000

there is another more scalable method, but that requires you to rebuild the tuple

//============UPDATE================
I found a way to loop the tuple without recursion, now it can exceeds length 1000 and limit only by the number of `OddNumbers`, still bounded by the max length of tuple(10,000)

which mean now it supports length up to 1997, unless we found a better way to generate all odd numbers up to 10,000, or you could just do it manually

```
type Odd<
    X extends number,
    Y extends unknown[] = [1],
    Z extends number = never
> = Y['length'] extends X
    ? Z | Y['length']
    : Odd<X, [1, 1, ...Y], Z | Y['length']>

type OddNumbers = Odd<1999> // 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | ....1997

type IsOddStringAndEvenNumberTuple<T extends unknown[]> = T extends [infer S, ...infer R] ? { [K in keyof [S, ...R]]: K extends `${OddNumbers}`
    ? T[K] extends number ? T[K] : "expect number type at even index"
    : T[K] extends string ? T[K] : "expect string type at Odd index" }
    : never

const isStringAndOddTuple = <T extends unknown[]>(tuple: T extends never ? T : IsOddStringAndEvenNumberTuple<T>) => {
    // don't neeed anything here
}

type C = IsOddStringAndEvenNumberTuple<[1, 2, 3, 4]>
//   ^?

type D = IsOddStringAndEvenNumberTuple<["a", "b", "c", "d"]>
//   ^?

type E = IsOddStringAndEvenNumberTuple<["a", 1, "b", 2]>
//   ^?

isStringAndOddTuple([1, 2, 3, 4])
isStringAndOddTuple(["a", "b", "c", "d"])
isStringAndOddTuple<["a", 1, "b", 2]>
```

[image]
[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-r1QZOxBLVxTEEQShSACYUkMUgAWD5oBsYAB6fkW0oAItP1rOC4Gi0vJSuw+uBTKBSkBbRP8aRb+BTgAVD1QY8oDPC9xygI4b3zAMF2LZ8yzXCR31-DJv1-TcQLAiDR1QHY-XvIMQ1XBMNygbdhn3KRKzQQi50LYMEGQ8i0K-H8v3-L8gNo+iiPgkhSNfVCP3SDisI+KAgA)

reference:
[Odd Number Type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71569082/5338829)

Answer (score 1):

An array index is a `number` type, and number types can either be any number (as `number`) or specific numbers (as `1 | 2 | 47`).

There aren't really any other options at the type level. This means that something like this not possible to annotate as of Typescript 4.9.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with Typescript. I wish you could. It would be a cool language feature.

The closest thing to an "even number" type would look something like the following. Wrap it in a class. Do the same thing with even numbers. Work out the kinks.

```
class EvenNumber {
  public constructor(n: number) {
    if (n % 2 != 0) {
      throw new Error("argument is not even:", n);
    }
    this.num = n;
  }
}
```